# why does my code give 'Use of expired sessions is not permitted' error

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
const {MongoClient} = require(" mongodb ");

const uri = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017";

const client = new MongoClient(uri);
const dbName = 'FruitsDB';

const db = client.db(dbName);

const collection = db.collection("fruits");

async function run() {
try {
await client.connect();
console.log("Successfully connected to the server");

    insertDocuments(db, collection);
    


} finally {
    // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
    await client.close();
}

}

const insertDocuments = async function(db, collection, callback){
try{

 // create an array of documents to insert
 const docs = [
    { 
      name: "Apple",
      score: 8,
      review: "Great fruit" 
  },
    { 
      name: "Orange",
      score: 6,
      review: "Kinda sour" 
  },
    { 
      name: "Banana",
      score: 9,
      review: "Great stuff!" 
  }
  ];

  // this option prevents additional documents from being inserted if one fails
  const options = { ordered: true };

  const result = await collection.insertMany(docs, options);

  console.log(`${result.insertedCount} documents were inserted`);
}
finally {
    await client.close();
  }

}

const findDocuments = async function(collection){

try{

const allFruits = collection.find();

await allFruits.forEach(function(fr){
    console.log(fr);
});
}finally {
    await client.close();
  }

}

run().catch(console.dir);
```

the above code is giving use of expired session not permitted error kindly help. if i remove the functions and paste the code inside run function it runs well.i am not able to find a solution anywhere kindly help.

i am currently learning mongodb and when going through the documentation i learned how to insert and find data and insert data using the native mongodb driver. i want to create different functions of insertion and finding by it gives an error.

Comment: Is it intentional that you are closing the connection more than once? That's probably causing at least one error